# Echo Category In Loop

Tags: categories, loop, get-theme-mod

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'stock' => 1,
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'product_cat' => '<?php echo get_theme_mod('vatname', 'Clothing'); ?>',
    'orderby' =>'date',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
global $product;
?>

<p><?php the_title(); ?></p>

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

I'm trying to echo the product category name. The custom loop works fine but when I echo the function:

```
<?php echo get_theme_mod( 'vatname', 'Clothing' ); ?>
```

The loop stops. Can anyone help me?
im trying to use wordpress cutomization api to enter the category name in loop
examole
'product_cat' => 'clothing',

so i made text function im trying to eco the value in product_cat buy i give sybtax error

Comment: Please write your question in human terms.  
I've made your code readable, so you can see a syntax error there.

Comment: `'product_cat' => '<?php echo get_theme_mod('vatname', 'Clothing'); ?>',` you're already in PHP...  try `'product_cat' => get_theme_mod('vatname', 'Clothing'),`

Comment: @jgraup You could formulate that into a nice answer :)

Comment: thank you but still syntax error  (T_STRING), expecting

Comment: im sorry for bad format in the post im just start working soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function [`get_theme_mod()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_theme_mod) returns information. Since you want to *assign* it and not echo it to the screen, we can remove the echo and PHP tags:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'stock'          => 1,
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'product_cat'    => get_theme_mod( 'vatname', 'Clothing' ),
    'orderby'        =>'date',
    'order'          => 'ASC'
);
```

That should fix your query. Now the query is going to return Posts ( products in this case ) so if we want the categories we need to use a function like [`wp_get_post_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_terms/) which returns an array of post ( product ) categories.

```
<?php
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
        $loop->the_post();
        global $product;
        $category_array = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
?>

        <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
        <?php print_r( $category_array ); ?>

<?php
    endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: @ScarletSoza You're welcome! If any of the posts here solved your issue, ensure to click the "checkmark" to show future readers which solution worked for you!

Comment: Ha! missed my answer window

Answer (score 0):

Are the opening and closing php tags for the product_cat arg killing the statement? Would this work:

```
$clothing = get_theme_mod('vatname', 'Clothing');
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'stock' => 1,
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'product_cat' => $clothing,
    'orderby' =>'date',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
```